# How does one count the indexes in an array with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have a JSON object through an AJAX request and I want to count the indexes in the array. However, each array within the array is an array itself. I want to set a variable to this number, so I can print it on a UI element, in reference to the number of records left to load.

Using jQuery, and I'm kind of stumped. There doesn't appear to be anything in jQuery that counts the indexes on an array. :|

I could also use PHP to accomplish the counting, but I wanted to keep it client-side if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "count indices"? Why can't you use `yourarray.length` or properly iterate and then do what you want?

Comment: Maybe `array.length` ?

Comment: The expected JSON result is contained of arrays. It's set to 12, or whatever is left once there's less than 12. I want to use the dynamic number to update a button (i.e. "load 12 more", "load 3 more")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property for your array.